# jQuery Retrieve the contents of an array of divs

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a collection of divs on a page with the same class name.

```
<div class="ProductName">Product Foo</div>
<div class="ProductName">Product Bar</div>
```

I would like to be able to retrieve, iterate through and this case alert the ProductName div's contents.

Currently I can retrieve and iterate, but I can't alert the individual contents.

```
var ExistingProductNamesOnscreen = $.makeArray($(".ProductName"));
$.each(ExistingProductNamesOnscreen, function (key, val) {
    alert(*ProductName contents*);
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your more elegant solutions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".ProductName").each(function(k, v) {
    alert($(v).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ProductName").each(function ()
{
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
alert ($(this).text());
```

or

```
alert ($(this).html());
```

?

(The first should alert `text` contents, while the latter also any tags found in particular `div`)